# Will deleting unnecessary files decrease the size of my Intel XDK app? If not, how can I go about this?

Tags: intel-xdk

I am trying to decrease the size of my app as much as possible because my app will have a lot of moving parts.  Will minimizing files and deleting files that are not used in the app decrease the size?  When installing a framework, you normally get more files than you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app is delivered it is delivered as a ZIP file (APK == ZIP, IPA == ZIP, XAP == ZIP, etc.). So it is compressed. Of course, images and similar objects are already compressed, so there is no decrease in size of these objects.

Certainly deleting unused files will help. Does your project have a unique `www` directory in the project, where the sources are located? This will help, especially with future releases. See this FAQ if you need help converting your project to one that contains a `www` directory > https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/faqs/general#www-folder

Comment: Yes it already has a www directory.  I installed "Bower Components" and I believe these packages have more files than necessary.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, some of those Bower libraries come with a whole lot of excess. :(